# How to get the Latitude and Longitude of RMMarker (Cloudmade iphone API)

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude

How do i get the latitude and longitude of a RMMarker? i can't see any method in the headers.

I would be very thankfull fur any help.

Answer (score 1):

If mapView is your RMMapView and marker is your RMMarker

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [mapView.markerManager latitudeLongitudeForMarker:marker];

NSLog(@"Latitude: %f", loc.latitude);
NSLog(@"Longitude: %f", loc.longitude);
```